# interactive content (html5 animation) on facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

I would like to post a dynamic content on facebook, say something like a sprite that follows a mouse cursor. So what I need is facebook my send HTML + Javascript + CSS to a client. How can I do it?

Can it be done by Facebook canvas? I have an access to a public web server where I can host my app and handle POST requests

Comment: Yes, canvas and page tab apps display external content in an iframe. (You need your content to be available via HTTPS.)

Comment: That was very helpful. Would you mind to make an answer from your comment, so I could accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [canvas](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/gamesonfacebook) and [page tab](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/tabs) apps display external content in an iframe.

You’ll need your content to be available via HTTPS (because facebook.com is served via HTTPS, and so your iframed content needs to be as well, otherwise the browser will block it as mixed/insecure content.)